# Binary classification with only "yes" instances

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, svm, knn

Imagine I have a problem of binary classification. I have to assign a label to each input element (yes or no) but in the training set I have only "yes" instances. This is common, because many times we would like to say if a given element is "similar" to the ones given or not. We can find possible examples in sound recognition or image recognition problems.

Example 1: We have many sounds of dog barks and given a new sound we want to say if it is a dog barking or not

Example 2: We have many pictures of dogs and given a new picture we want to say if it represents a dog

In common machine learning problems, the training set is composed by "yes" instances and "no" instances and given a new element the classifier establishes if it is more similar to the "yes" instances or to the "no".

As expected from the above described scenarios, we can't have "no" instances because they would be all possible other sounds/pictures of the world.

Which machine learning methods (svm, neural networks,knn,...) could be used to solve these kind of problems?

Comment: the keywords you are looking for are "one class classification", "density estimation" "outlier detection" "novelty detection"

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem called novelty detection.

Specifically, you have a dataset which is considered noise free. E.g. You have a collection of data which represents a selection of dog barks.

If you had some dog barks and some cat meows, and wanted to find the frontier to separate the dogs from the cats, this is an outlier detection problem.

A simple example can be found on the SKlearn documentation website

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_oneclass.html#example-svm-plot-oneclass-py

The specific implementation will depend on exactly what your data looks like - there is no catch all solution. Via the 'No Free Lunch' Theorem, there does not exist an algorithm which performs the best across a range of problems.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry if this sounds like i'm advertising my work but:
You can use negative selection to create a **NO** set, based only on the **YES** set and then train a Neuron Network to perform the classification.
try searching for the NSNN algorithm by Marin Pamukov. I was able to get MCC north of 0.9 for binary classification by using only the **YES** set.
I'm posting this response despite the age of the question just in case someone else looks for an answer.

Link to ResearchGate: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327196213_Negative_Selection_and_Neural_Network_Based_Algorithm_for_Intrusion_Detection_in_IoT